# CLion rename header file

Tags: c++, clion

Does somebody know is it possible to rename a hpp file in such way that CLion will automatically change preprocessor directives of the corresponding file? For me it does not do that.

Comment: FYI, all compilers supported by CLion support `#pragma once`, which you might find more convenient.

Comment: Not yet. Please, vote for the issue! 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1478

Answer (score 3):

You can apply rename twice: one to the filename and once to the include guard symbol.